# Malware? .systemRootModeFile in ~/users/me/library

Tags: macos, java

Non-techie person asks:

There is a `.systemRootModeFile` in `~/users/me/library`.

Is it malware, something horrible?

In the hidden library folder in `~/users/me` I have a folder named `.f5cd`.
Inside that is a folder hierarchy of `.java/.systemPrefs/_!%...` - the last one being a string of about 25 characters - and the folder name is in bold.

Inside that is a file `prefs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE map SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd">
<map MAP_XML_VERSION="1.0">
  <entry key="EXPDATE" value="4994"/>
  <entry key="REGVER" value="2"/>
</map>
```

and also within the `.systemPrefs` folder are two more files
`.system.lock` and `.systemRootModFile`.

Comment: For a non-techie person you dig deep :)...what does your virus scanner says?

Comment: FYI, `~` means your Home folder (`/Users/me/`) so `~/Users/me/Library` actually means `/Users/me/Users/me/Library` :) `~/Library` refers to your Library folder in your Home folder, and so does `/Users/me/Library`, however combining `~` with `/Users/me/Library` refers to a completely different folder :)

Comment: It says it is your JAVA preferences file. the Link will get you to Oracle download.

Comment: Do you have something similar in your system - particularly the .systemRootModFile  file?

Comment: WHat java programs have you installed - as they can implement the preferencesFactory in several ways

Answer (score -1):

.systemRootModFile and the other files you mentioned are part of Java system preferences and are safe. See [this thread](http://www.freag.net/en/t/3umsk/unexplained_fil).